# React native elements tooltip is giving error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

code ->

```
    <Tooltip
      ref={props.toolref}
      containerStyle={styles.reelDeletionMenu}
      overlayColor="rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.8)"
      withPointer={false}
      popover={
        <ReelDeletionMenu
          toolref={props.toolref}
         
        />
      }>
      <MaterialIcons name="more-vert" color="#d4d4d4" size={21} />
   </Tooltip>
```

when I'm using react-native-elements tooltip I'm getting this error
is there anything wrong in my code or what

[[4,4,4,4,17],[2,17,2,2,5],[[3067,"RCTText",1,{"ellipsizeMode":"tail","accessible":true,"fontStyle":"normal","fontWeight":"normal","color":-2829100}] not usable in native method what is this error?

Comment: What is `ReelDeletionMenu` and why are using same refs for two elements?

Comment: ReelDeletionMenu is a component I’m sending props toolref is for toggle tooltip